# how to get a data from database of django and display it in html

Tags: django

I am new to django and i am trying to get data from the database based on a key and include it into html

this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Car(models.Model):
    billing_number = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial_number = models.BigIntegerField()
    mfg_date = models.DateTimeField()
    shipping_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

This is my forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Car

class CarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        exclude = ()

class CarAccessForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('billing_number',)
```

This is my views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
from .forms import CarForm, CarAccessForm


def add_car(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  # data sent by user
        form = CarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # this will save Car info to database
            return render(request,'saved.html')
    else:  # display empty form
        form = CarForm()
    return render(request, 'add_car.html', {'car_form': form})

def get_car(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  # data sent by user
        form = CarAccessForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # this will save Car info to database
            return render(request,'saved.html')
    else:  # display empty form
        form = CarAccessForm()
    return render(request, 'get_car.html', {'car_form': form})
```

how can i change them to display data based on key value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get data without change page use Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript)

1. send data from ajax to view
2. In the view, prepare the data as json and return them

to return them you can use JsonResponse